# How to solve initial value problem of non linear first order ODE if one solution is given?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

We have given Nonlinear ODE as $y'=y+e^x-e^{-x}y^2$ and one of its solution is given by $y(x)=-e^x$.

Is it possible to find solution of IVP with $y(0)=6$?

If it is linear ODE then by equating constant we can get solution.

But how to solve problem if it is non linear ODE?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Riccati equation. The second solution approach consists in setting $y=e^x\frac{u'}{u}$ so that
\begin{align}
y'&=e^x\frac{u'}{u}+e^x\frac{u''}{u}-e^x\frac{u'^2}{u^2}=y+e^x\frac{u''}{u}-e^{-x}y^2
\\
&=y+e^x-e^{-x}y^2
\\[1em]
\implies
u''=u\implies u&=Ae^x+Be^{-x},~~y=e^x\frac{Ae^x-Be^{-x}}{Ae^x+Be^{-x}}
\end{align}
where pairs $(A,B)$ with the same ratio give the same solution. Your given solution corresponds to $A=0$, $B=1$.

---

For the solution with $y(0)=6$ you want $u(0)=1$, $u'(0)=6$, thus $u(x)=\cosh(x)+6\sinh(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Riccati equation, using the $y=-e^x+\frac{1}{v}$ substitution,
then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-e^x-\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{dv}{dx},$$
plugged into the
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y+e^x+e^{-x}y^2$$
you can get
$$\frac{dv}{dx}+3v=e^{-x}$$
this is in
$$ \frac{dv}{dx}+pv=q$$
form. You can use an integrating factor to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'=y+e^x-e^{-x}y^2$$
Lutz and Dinush have answered your question. Note that you can also easily solve it this way:
$$(y'-y)=e^x-e^{-x}y^2$$
$$(ye^{-x})'=1-(e^{-x}y)^2$$
Then substitute $u=ye^{-x}$
$$u'=1-u^2$$
This DE is separable.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Thank you @Dinush ....